# (+) Join whith a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to change a condition from an existant query.The condition is like that :

```
and (w.wthd_class (+) = 'A' or w.wthd_class (+) = 'B')
```

So what i want is to don't let this condition static i wan't to retrieve `WTHD_CLASS` values dynamically from a subquery but in the same time don't loose the `right outer join (+)` :

```
and (w.wthd_class (+) IN ( SELECT WTHD_CLASS FROM myTABLE T WHERE T.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT )
```

But this syntax give this Error :

> ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Can someone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Learn to use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.  It's time.

Comment: I'm surprised the original condition works. My recollection is that the older outer join syntax can't be used with `IN` or `OR`.

Comment: @DavidFaber without the second (+) yes it will not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
 from table1 a,
     (select * from table2 b
      where b.column1 = 'somevalue') x
where a.column1 (+) = x.column1
```

Comment: the subquery should return one row ?

Comment: No, not necessary. you can write such way:
select *
 from table1 a,
     (select * from table2 b
      where b.column1 in('somevalue1', 'somevalue2') x
where a.column1 (+) = x.column1

Answer (score 3):

Use ANSI join syntax:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1 b
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 w
       ON ( b.some_column = w.some_column )
       RIGHT OUTER JOIN mytable t
       ON (
             t.account    = b.account
         AND w.wthd_class = t.wthd_class
       );
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too smart example based on Scott's schema, but you'll get the idea, I hope.

The old Oracle outer join (+) operator:

```
SQL> SELECT e.deptno,
  2         e.ename,
  3         e.job,
  4         e.sal
  5    FROM emp e, dept d
  6   WHERE     e.deptno(+) = d.deptno
  7         AND ROWNUM < 5;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        20 SMITH      CLERK            800
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
        30 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975
```

It won't work when outer joining with a subquery:

```
SQL> SELECT e.deptno,
  2         e.ename,
  3         e.job,
  4         e.sal
  5    FROM emp e, dept d
  6   WHERE     e.deptno(+) = (SELECT d.deptno
  7                              FROM dept d)
  8         AND ROWNUM < 5;
       AND ROWNUM < 5
       *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
```

So, use ANSI outer join:

```
SQL> SELECT e.deptno,
  2         e.ename,
  3         e.job,
  4         e.sal
  5    FROM emp e
  6         RIGHT JOIN (SELECT d.deptno
  7                       FROM dept d) x
  8            ON x.deptno = e.deptno
  9   WHERE ROWNUM < 5;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        20 SMITH      CLERK            800
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
        30 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975

SQL>
```

Finally, a "normal" outer join, without a subquery:

```
SQL> SELECT e.deptno,
  2         e.ename,
  3         e.job,
  4         e.sal
  5    FROM emp e RIGHT JOIN dept d
  6                       ON d.deptno = e.deptno
  7   WHERE rownum < 5;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
        20 SMITH      CLERK            800
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN        1600
        30 WARD       SALESMAN        1250
        20 JONES      MANAGER         2975

SQL>
```

Comment: Why have a `SELECT` statement in the join of the final example? Just do `emp e RIGHT JOIN dept x ON x.deptno = e.deptno`.

Comment: @MT0: to show that - using ANSI RIGHT JOIN - it is possible to outer join a column to a subquery (which is where the OP faced a problem).

Comment: It's possible with the older syntax as well if you use the subquery as a table (which is what you're doing here)